# Two blocks, one on top of the other, with three springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm currently working through some questions on normal modes of oscillation and came across this question from TAMU's Physics qualifying exam ([http://people.tamu.edu/~abanov/QE/CM.pdf](http://people.tamu.edu/%7Eabanov/QE/CM.pdf) Problem 81). The attached diagram is below and the surfaces are all frictionless:

[image]

My problem right now is with properly writing down the Lagrangian of the system. Suppose we wanted to choose the generalized coordinates of the system as $x_1$ and $x_2$, corresponding to the centre of mass of the larger mass and the smaller mass, respectively, where $x_1=x_2=0$ is the initial position of the centre of mass of the system. I think I might be confusing myself with the frame of references by which I define the position and velocity to get the Lagrangian.

For the kinetic energy part, I'm thinking that the larger mass would have $T = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x_1}^2$, but would the smaller mass now have $T=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x_2}+\dot{x_1})^2$ since it is on top of the mass that is moving?

Similarly with the potential energy part, I think the larger mass is quite simple in that it has $V=\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2$. However, I'm also not sure about the smaller mass, given that it is riding on top of the larger mass, whether it would just be $V=\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2+\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2$ or whether it would be $V=\frac{1}{2}k(x_1-x_2)^2+\frac{1}{2}k(x_1-x_2)^2$ because of the relative position of $x_2$ with respect to $x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

The kinetic energy for both $x_1$ (assume mass $m_1$ just for distinction): $\frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x_1^2$.

The kinetic energy for both $x_2$ (assume mass $m_2$ just for distinction): $\frac{1}{2}m_2  (\dot x_2+ \dot x_1)^2$.

Potentail energy for $m_1$: $\frac{1}{2} k x_1^2$.

Potentail energy for $m_2$: $\frac{1}{2} 2 k x_2^2 = k x_2^2$.

These terms render a Lagrangian:

$$
  L = \frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2  (\dot x_2+ \dot x_1)^2 -\frac{1}{2} k x_1^2 - k x_2^2.
$$

This Lagrangian leads to equation of motion by
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x_i}= 0$

For $x_1$:

$$ \tag{1}
  (m_1 + m_2) \ddot x_1 = - k_1 x_1 - m_2 \ddot x_2.  
$$

And for  $x_2$:
$$\tag{2}
  m_2 \ddot x_2 = - 2 k_2 x_2 - m_2 \ddot x_1.  
$$

These two equations are reasonable. The Eq.(1) for $x_1$ has mass $m_1+m_2$ and taking into account of the acceleration effect for $m_2$. The Eq.(2) is for $m_2$ takineg into the consideration of the fictitious force for being in the accelleration frame of $x_1$. The term $m_2 \ddot x_2$ in Eq.(1) is some surprising, but it shoud be corret after a deeper considerations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could I ask why the potential energy for $m_2$ only involves $x_2^2$ instead of $(x_1-x_2)^2$?

Comment: It is quite clear, The potential of $x_2$ is only dependent on the two springs that connecting on $m_2$, nothing to do with $x_1$.

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are considered two independent variables. The only one that cannot be separated is the velocity of $\dot x_2$, because $x_2$ is on the $x_1$ frame. But the strength of the spring connecting to $m_2$ is nothintg to do with the position of $x_1$. (The fictitious force will comes in later.)

Comment: Okay, I understand the potential part. For the Kinetic Energy part, could I also ask why it would be incorrect to have $T = \frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)\dot{x_1}^2+\frac{1}{2}(m_2)\dot{x_2}^2$?

Comment: No. You have to keep your thinking straight. The $m_1$ has velocity $\dot x_1$, and therefore kinetic energy $m_1 \dot x_1^2 / 2$. Then the $m_2$ has velocity $\dot x_2 + \dot x_1$, therefore its kinetic energy $m_2 ( \dot x_2 + \dot x_1)^2 / 2$. In your writing, the velocity of $m_2$ becomes $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$,, which don't make sense.